# Change the format of list in list into specific order in python

Tags: python, list

> I have this type of nested list data.

```
array =[
['PRODUCT NAME PACK', 'BAIGAM KOT', 'FIAZ BAGH', 'OLD ANARKALI', 'SULTAN PURA', 'TEZAB AAHATA', 'GHORAY SHAH', 'KOT KHAWAJA SAEED']
['002188', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', '3']
['PRODUCT NAME PACK', 'BAGHBAN PURA', 'GAWAL MANDI', 'OLD ANARKALI', 'MAYO HOSPITAL', 'GARHI SHAHU BAZAR', 'BILAL GUNJ', 'LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL']
['002188', '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['008999', 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0]
['012961', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', 0]
]
```

> Want this type of output from this list.

```
array =[
[['PRODUCT NAME PACK', 'BAIGAM KOT', 'FIAZ BAGH', 'OLD ANARKALI', 'SULTAN PURA', 'TEZAB AAHATA', 'GHORAY SHAH', 'KOT KHAWAJA SAEED']
['002188', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', '3']]
[['PRODUCT NAME PACK', 'BAGHBAN PURA', 'GAWAL MANDI', 'OLD ANARKALI', 'MAYO HOSPITAL', 'GARHI SHAHU BAZAR', 'BILAL GUNJ', 'LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL']
['002188', '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['008999', 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0]
['012961', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', 0]]
]
```

Comment: what type of "list" data is that? a pandas dataframe? without comma separators between elements, neither of those are lists...

Comment: it a comma separated list in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```py
array = [
    [
        "PRODUCT NAME PACK",
        "BAIGAM KOT",
        "FIAZ BAGH",
        "OLD ANARKALI",
        "SULTAN PURA",
        "TEZAB AAHATA",
        "GHORAY SHAH",
        "KOT KHAWAJA SAEED",
    ],
    ["002188", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2", "3"],
    [
        "PRODUCT NAME PACK",
        "BAGHBAN PURA",
        "GAWAL MANDI",
        "OLD ANARKALI",
        "MAYO HOSPITAL",
        "GARHI SHAHU BAZAR",
        "BILAL GUNJ",
        "LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL",
    ],
    ["002188", "3", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ["008999", 0, 0, 0, 0, "1", 0, 0],
    ["012961", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "3", 0],
]

outer = []
for item in array:
    if "PRODUCT NAME PACK" in item:
        inner = []
        outer.append(inner)
    inner.append(item)

print(outer)
```

That gives me:

```sh
➜  nested python main.py 
[[['PRODUCT NAME PACK', 'BAIGAM KOT', 'FIAZ BAGH', 'OLD ANARKALI', 'SULTAN PURA', 'TEZAB AAHATA', 'GHORAY SHAH', 'KOT KHAWAJA SAEED'], ['002188', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', '3']], [['PRODUCT NAME PACK', 'BAGHBAN PURA', 'GAWAL MANDI', 'OLD ANARKALI', 'MAYO HOSPITAL', 'GARHI SHAHU BAZAR', 'BILAL GUNJ', 'LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL'], ['002188', '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['008999', 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0], ['012961', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', 0]]]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  "BAIGAM KOT" has zero value that is place in second index after "002188". Is it possible to make it in one array like this.    ["002188", "BAIGAM KOT",0]     and     ["002188", "FIAZ BAGH",0]     and so on. Because each "PRODUCT NAME PACK" list contain value in next array and so on.

Comment: I was just going off of the output you said you expected. If you expect something else, update your question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70043791/change-and-sort-list-in-list-in-specific-order-in-python