# Change and Sort list in list in specific order in python

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops

Hello guys I have this type of data in list in list

```
array = [
[
    "PRODUCT NAME PACK",
    "BAIGAM KOT",
    "FIAZ BAGH",
    "OLD ANARKALI",
    "SULTAN PURA",
    "TEZAB AAHATA",
    "GHORAY SHAH",
    "KOT KHAWAJA SAEED",
],
["002188", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2", "3"],
[
    "PRODUCT NAME PACK",
    "BAGHBAN PURA",
    "GAWAL MANDI",
    "OLD ANARKALI",
    "MAYO HOSPITAL",
    "GARHI SHAHU BAZAR",
    "BILAL GUNJ",
    "LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL",
],
["002188", "3", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
["008999", 0, 0, 0, 0, "1", 0, 0],
["012961", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "3", 0],
]
```

Each list that contain `"PRODUCT NAME PACK"` has actual city name and their values are placed in next list like `"BAIGAM KOT"` has value 0 after the item code "002188". I want to loop through it into table in which it get the value in each row like that

```
[["002188", "BAIGAM KOT",0],["002188","FIAZ BAGH" ,0],["002188", "OLD ANARKALI",0]["002188", "SULTAN PURA",0],["002188","TEZAB AAHATA" ,0],["002188","GHORAY SHAH", "2"],["002188", "KOT KHAWAJA SAEED","3"]]
```

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: you will have to use `for`-loop with some `if/else` to run different code for different lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `for`-loop with `if/else` to run different code for different lists.

For list with `"PRODUCT NAME PACK"` you have to keep list with names in variable - so you may use it in next loops when you get list with numbers

For other list you can keep first number as `index` and rest use in `zip(names, numbers)` to create pairs `(name, number)` which can be used to create `[index, name, number]`

```
array = [
    [
        "PRODUCT NAME PACK",
        "BAIGAM KOT",
        "FIAZ BAGH",
        "OLD ANARKALI",
        "SULTAN PURA",
        "TEZAB AAHATA",
        "GHORAY SHAH",
        "KOT KHAWAJA SAEED",
    ],
    ["002188", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2", "3"],
    [
        "PRODUCT NAME PACK",
        "BAGHBAN PURA",
        "GAWAL MANDI",
        "OLD ANARKALI",
        "MAYO HOSPITAL",
        "GARHI SHAHU BAZAR",
        "BILAL GUNJ",
        "LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL",
    ],
    ["002188", "3", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ["008999", 0, 0, 0, 0, "1", 0, 0],
    ["012961", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "3", 0],
]

# --- convert ---

result = []
#names = None  # default value at start  

for data in array:
    if data[0] == "PRODUCT NAME PACK":
        names = data[1:]
    else:
        index = data[0]
        numbers = data[1:]
        for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
            result.append( [index, name, number] )
            
# --- display ---

for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
['002188', 'BAIGAM KOT', 0]
['002188', 'FIAZ BAGH', 0]
['002188', 'OLD ANARKALI', 0]
['002188', 'SULTAN PURA', 0]
['002188', 'TEZAB AAHATA', 0]
['002188', 'GHORAY SHAH', '2']
['002188', 'KOT KHAWAJA SAEED', '3']
['002188', 'BAGHBAN PURA', '3']
['002188', 'GAWAL MANDI', 0]
['002188', 'OLD ANARKALI', 0]
['002188', 'MAYO HOSPITAL', 0]
['002188', 'GARHI SHAHU BAZAR', 0]
['002188', 'BILAL GUNJ', 0]
['002188', 'LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL', 0]
['008999', 'BAGHBAN PURA', 0]
['008999', 'GAWAL MANDI', 0]
['008999', 'OLD ANARKALI', 0]
['008999', 'MAYO HOSPITAL', 0]
['008999', 'GARHI SHAHU BAZAR', '1']
['008999', 'BILAL GUNJ', 0]
['008999', 'LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL', 0]
['012961', 'BAGHBAN PURA', 0]
['012961', 'GAWAL MANDI', 0]
['012961', 'OLD ANARKALI', 0]
['012961', 'MAYO HOSPITAL', 0]
['012961', 'GARHI SHAHU BAZAR', 0]
['012961', 'BILAL GUNJ', '3']
['012961', 'LADY WELLINGTON HOSPITAL', 0]
```